# Can I trust user input here?

Tags: python, file, security, bc

I have a discord bot that executes

```
with open("input.bc", "w") as f:
                f.write(INPUT)
```

where INPUT is a string limited to 2000 characters. this file later gets deleted. Is this safe if INPUT is whatever the user wishes it to be?

then runs the bc file (google bc programming language if you are curios)

by the way, this file later gets executed with

```
execlp("bc", "bc", "-q", "bc_funcs/lib.bc", "bc_funcs/init.bc",
               FILE_NAME, "bc_funcs/exit.bc", NULL);
```

forgot to mention: After 5 seconds if the bc file doesnt finish executing the process is stopped.

Comment: You accept any user input, put it into a file and execute it. Does it sound safe to you?

Comment: @khelwood it is a bc file, so it doesn't sound that bad.

Comment: Writing is safe, but you should consider using an absolute path for the file. Running it is a whole different thing and not safe at all.

Comment: @KlausD. it is a bc file though? cant find anything unsafe in the manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html
This is not the case, but if you had a programming language that runs only "1+1", would it be safe to execute anything? Why is bc any different?

Comment: The very least you can do is to occupy system resources until it crashes.

Comment: @KlausD. if the file doesn't execute in 5 seconds it gets "killed" :)

Comment: @Lainad--bc seems safe since 1) it has only limited operations (i.e. unlike something like eval which has unlimited operations), 2) it has limited execution time, 3) Google search does not show any references to safety issues.

Answer (score 1):

The question wording is a little misleading, you would not be trusting user input. User input cannot be trusted.

You will be trusting `bc` though. I don't know `bc` to this detail, but it appears to not allow malicious operations. The reason you would still probably not want to run arbitrary user input is exactly because of that trust in the bc **implementation** that you have. Probably it was not supposed to allow arbitrary operations beyond maths, and there is no known vulnerability that I can find, but these implementations might have vulnerabilities that people have just not discovered yet. In case of `bc` I think the risk of a potential vulnerability is increased by the fact that not a lot of research might have gone into finding such vulnerabilities.

So in short, while there might not be a known vulnerability right now, my take is it would probably be possible to exploit bc in a way that compromises your server.

Another potential vulnerability (depending on your attacker model) is the file operation involved. You are writing user input to a file (which is fine), and then separate from that you read that file and run it in `bc`. An attacker might be able to add path elements to run something else as `bc` on the server, or replace the written .bc file with something else before being run, potentially creating incorrect results (and that's only the best case). File operations are tricky to get right if you assume some level of access for an attacker.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you just let any user do input and than execue it. It's kinda not safe, if a lot of users will use it.

Comment: same thing i said to KlausD.
it is a bc file. can't find anything unsafe in the manual. gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html This is not the case, but if you had a programming language that runs only "1+1", would it be safe to execute anything? Why is bc any different?